# Recreate output of tail -n to text files

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

I had a bunch of bash scripts in a directory that I "backed up" doing `$ tail -n +1 -- *.sh`

The output of that tail is something like:

```
==> do_stuff.sh <==
#! /bin/bash
cd ~/my_dir
source ~/my_dir/bin/activate
python scripts/do_stuff.py


==> do_more_stuff.sh <==
#! /bin/bash
cd ~/my_dir
python scripts/do_more_stuff.py
```

These are all fairly simple scripts with 2-10 lines.
Given the output of that `tail`, I want to recreate all of the above files with the same content.
That is, I'm looking for a command that can ingest the above text and create `do_stuff.sh` and `do_more_stuff.sh` with the appropriate content.

This is more of a one-off task so I don't really need anything robust and I believe there are no big edge cases given files are simple (e.g none of the files actually contain `==>` in them).

I started with trying to come up with a matching regex and it will probably look something like this `(==>.*\.sh <==)(.*)(==>.*\.sh <==)`, but I'm stuck into actually getting it to capture filename, content and output to file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presume your backup file is named backup.txt

```
perl -ne "if (/==> (\S+) <==/){open OUT,'>',$1;next}print OUT $_" backup.txt
```

Above version is for Windows

fixed version on *nix:

```
perl -ne 'if (/==> (\S+) <==/){open OUT,">",$1;next}print OUT $_' backup.txt
```

Comment: Please fix quoting. Bash replaces `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^==\>[[:space:]](.*)[[:space:]]\<==$ ]]; then
    out="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    continue
  fi
  printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$out"
done < backup.txt
```

Drawback: extra blank line at the end of every created file except the last one.